# How to restart service (basically Java program) based on its log?

Tags: linux, bash, java, services

I have a Java program that runs as a service on Ubuntu 16.04. Probably the only output i get from it - it is a logs(errors, usual prints, etc.). So what i want to do is to whenever there is a Exception thrown in my program - i want to restart it (do systemctl restart myjavaservice).

What i already tried to do is to write logs in file with `tea -a`(-a because i want to keep really old logs) and  use tail with awk like this:
`tail -F /home/myuser/myservice/output.log | awk '/Exception/ {system("systemctl restart myjavaservice")}'` 
But this makes the service restart to many times and basically service fails to restart properly.

Im assuming i can put a script in a cron job (that will run every 5 minutes or so), that script will check logs of my service and if it encounter word "Exception" (or any other word) i want to restart service (but also do not clear the logfile).
Is there any proper way to do this? What tools shoud i use?

P.S.: Currently im thinking of `tail -n 200 /home/myuser/myservice/output.log | awk '{if (/Exception/) {system("systemctl restart myjavaservice"); exit;}}'`

Am i right that this will pipe last 200 lines of log into awk and awk will check if there is any occurence of word Exception in passed text and if it is it will run systemctl restart myjavaservice and exit right after it will find first occurence?
Thank you in advance for your advices!

Comment: If the exception causes the program to stop, you can configure the systemd unit to automatically restart by adding line `Restart=on-failure` in the `[Service]` section.

Comment: @meuh No, it dont. Thats why i need to restart it manually. Thank you for you suggestion, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will need mechanism to make sure you do not re-read the same lines. Here is one way you can do what you are looking for.

1 #!/bin/sh
  2
  3 export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
  4
  5 PATTERN="Exception string"
  6 LOGFILE=/home/myuser/myservice/output.log
  7
  8 #-- Create flag file in the same locations as the log file
  9 FLAG=`dirname "$LOGFILE"`/`basename "$LOGFILE"`.flag
 10
 11 if [ ! -s "$FLAG" ] ; then
 12         LAST_LINE_NBR=0
 13         LAST_LINE=""
 14 else
 15         LAST_LINE_NBR=`sed 's/:.*$//' "$FLAG"`
 16         LAST_LINE=`sed 's/^[0-9]*: //' "$FLAG"`
 17
 18         #-- Validate if the file is same
 19         CURR_LINE=`sed -n $LAST_LINE_NBR,${LAST_LINE_NBR}p "$LOGFILE"`
 20
 21         if [ "$LAST_LINE" != "$CURR_LINE" ] ; then
 22                 #-- Logfile is no longer the same as previously checked, start over
 23                 LAST_LINE_NBR=0
 24                 LAST_LINE=""
 25         fi
 26 fi
 27
 28 #-- Pick line after the previously checked line
 29 LAST_LINE_NBR=`expr $LAST_LINE_NBR+1`
 30
 31 #-- Update flag
 32 NEW_LAST_LINE_NBR=`sed -n '$=' "$LOGFILE"`
 33 NEW_LAST_LINE=`sed -n $NEW_LAST_LINE_NBR,${NEW_LAST_LINE_NBR}p  "$LOGFILE"`
 34 echo "$NEW_LAST_LINE_NBR: $NEW_LAST_LINE" > "$FLAG"
 35
 36 sed -n $LAST_LINE_NBR,\$p "$LOGFILE" \
 37 | egrep "$PATTERN" > /dev/null
 38
 39 if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
 40         #-- Exception found, do the action
 41         systemctl restart myjavaservice
 42 fi
 43
 44 # end of file #

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but i have ended it doing a little more than an i wanted to initially. Now im slicing logs, backuping them, and i made sure that my script reads only current log.